# Not able to set google speech constructor using credential options

Tags: google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api

Hello I am trying not to use json approach and to use credential option to initiate the gcloud speech client.

```
         const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

         const client = new speech.SpeechClient({credentials:{private_key : "", client_email: ""}}});
```

but this is giving me  *Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument error.*

I have used dialog flow and other services in the same fashion and that is working fine, please advise if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
   const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');
   const config = { projectId: 'your-project', keyFilename:'key.json'};
   const client = new speech.SpeechClient(config);
```

In your code you have an extra **}**, this worked for me.

```
   const client = new speech.SpeechClient({credentials:{private_key : private_key, client_email: client_email}});
```

Comment: Thanks, is ````const client = new speech.SpeechClient({credentials:{private_key : private_key, client_email: client_email}});```` working for you?

Comment: yes, is working for me, I do not know what you pass for private_key, and client_email.